# Hola Amigos, ayuda con boton de "Regresar" no funciona y me genera un exception!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

lo que pasa es que estoy validando eventos con `<a></a>` y el detalle que estos son para regresar al momento de llenar formularios, el problema es que no se como manejar unas excepciones ya que me generan estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Despues de aplastar el boton de regresar me genera esta exception en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero mas que nada es controlar esa excepción con `Jquery` o `javaScript` para que solo me regrese a la pantalla anterior, este es mi código que controlo esa funcionalidad, pero por alguna extraña razón no funciona!

```
function regresarPaso2(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     var seguro = $('#seguro').val();
    var pension = $('#pension').val();
    var parametros = "?seguro=" + seguro + "&pension=" + pension;
    window.location.assign("paso-02.jsp" + parametros);
}
```

Y el codigo del boton es este:

```
<div id="bt_div" class="derecha exiit">
                    <!--<a href="../views/paso-02.jsp" class="exit" >Regresar</a>-->
                    <a href="paso-02.jsp" onclick="regresarPaso2(event);return false;" class="exit">Regresar</a>
                    <!--<a href="../views/paso-02.jsp" class="exit">Regresar</a>-->
                </div>
```

Ya por ultimo envio como tal todo el codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simulador Pensi&oacute;n</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
        <!--<script src="../comun/js/jquery_v1.11.3.js"></script>-->
        <script src="../js/jquery_v1.11.3.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/EnmascaraV2-AEM.js"></script>-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/DataLayer/dataLayer.js"></script><!--listo-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataLayer/dataLayer_.js"></script>listo-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/DataLayer/funciones_dataLayer.js"></script><!--listo-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/focusEfecto.js"></script>-->


        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

        <!--Para QA-->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_MD.css">-->
        <!--fin-->
        <!--Ruta Mi local-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style_MD_cta.css">

        <!--<script src="/comun/DataLayer/dataLayer.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="/comun/DataLayer/funciones_dataLayer.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/aplicativos/simulador-pensiones/globos/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/seleccion.js"></script>
        <%--<%@include file="/comun/DataLayer/dtm.txt" %>--%>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            <%
                /**
                 * ***********************************
                 * Migracion everis 03/Octubre/2013 autor: Victor Lujan
                 * ***********************************
                 */
            %>
            var string_pension = "";
            var string_seguro = "";
            $(function () {
                /****** Datos del paso 2 ******/
                var HON = '<%=(request.getParameter("HON") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("HON")%>';
                document.getElementById("HON").value = HON;
                var HOS = '<%=(request.getParameter("HOS") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("HOS")%>';
                document.getElementById("HOS").value = HOS;
                var HOD = '<%=(request.getParameter("HOD") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("HOD")%>';
                document.getElementById("HOD").value = HOD;
                var ASC = '<%=(request.getParameter("ASC") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("ASC")%>';
                document.getElementById("ASC").value = ASC;
                var esposa = '<%=(request.getParameter("esposa") == null) ? "false" : request.getParameter("esposa")%>';
                document.getElementById("esposa").value = esposa;
                /****** Datos del index ******/
                var seguro = '<%=request.getParameter("seguro")%>';
                document.getElementById("seguro").value = seguro;
                var pension = '<%=request.getParameter("pension")%>';
                document.getElementById("pension").value = pension;

            });
            var pension = '<%=request.getParameter("pension")%>';
            if (pension == "1") {
                string_pension = "invalidez";
            } else if (pension == "2") {
                string_pension = "incapacidad";
            } else if (pension == "3") {
                string_pension = "viudez y orfandad";
            } else if (pension == "4") {
                string_pension = "viudez";
            } else if (pension == "5") {
                string_pension = "orfandad";
            } else if (pension == "6") {
                string_pension = "ascendencia";
            } else {
                string_pension = "";
            }
            var seg = '<%=(request.getParameter("seguro") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("seguro")%>';
            if (seg = "1") {
                string_seguro = "invalidez";
            } else if (seg = "2") {
                string_seguro = "riesgos de trabajo";
            } else if (seg = "3") {
                string_pseguro = "Viudez y Orfandad";
            }


            <%
                int seguro, pension = 0;
                seguro = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("seguro"));
                pension = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pension"));
                if (seguro == 2 && pension == 2) {
            %>
            string_pension = "incapacidad";
            $(function () {
                $("#PDI").prop('disabled', false);
            });
            <%}
                if (seguro == 1 && pension == 1) {%>
            string_pension = "invalidez";
            $(function () {
                $("#AAS").val('10');
            });
            <%}
                if ((seguro == 1 || seguro == 2) && (pension == 5 || pension == 6)) {

                    if (pension == 5) {

            %>
            string_pension = "orfandad";
            <%    } else {
            %>
            string_pension = "ascendencia";
            <%
                }

            %>
            $(function () {
                $("#AAS").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#PDI").prop('disabled', true);
            });
            <%}
                if (seguro == 3 && (pension == 3 || pension == 4)) {

                    if (pension == 3) {

            %>
            string_pension = "viudez y orfandad";
            <%    } else {
            %>
            string_pension = "viudez";
            <%
                }
            %>
            $(function () {
                $("#SP").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#PDI").prop('disabled', true);
            });
            <%} else if (seguro == 3) {%>
            $(function () {
                $("#SP").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#AAS").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#PDI").prop('disabled', true);
            });
            <%}%>
            function enviar(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ($('#seguro').val() == 3) {
                    document.paso3.submit();
                } else if (document.getElementById('SP').value == 0) {

                } else
                {
                    document.paso3.submit();
                }
            }





        </script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Simulador Pensi&oacute;n</h1>       
            <h2>Datos de pensi&oacute;n:</h2>

            <!--<form name="paso3" method="post" action="../views/paso-04.jsp">-->
                <form name="paso3" method="post" action="paso-04.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="HON" id="HON" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="HOS" id="HOS" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="HOD" id="HOD" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="ASC" id="ASC" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="esposa" id="esposa" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="seguro" id="seguro" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="pension" id="pension" value="">
                <div class="botonera">      
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                        <div class="group">
                            <input  name="SP" size="10" id="SP"  type="text"><label class="labelPosicion ">Pesos</label>
                            <span class="highlight"></span>
                            <label for="SP" >Salario Pensionable</label>
                        </div>
                        <p class=" cond SP_alert"></p>
                    </div>





                    <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                        <div class="group">                           
                            <select class="selectArrow" name="AAS" class="Caja_txt_246" id="AAS" tabindex="9">
                                <option selected="selected" value="0">0 %</option>
                                <option value="5">5 %</option>
                                <option value="10">10 %</option>
                                <option value="15">15 %</option>
                                <option value="20">20 %</option>
                            </select>



                            <label for="AAS" class="combo" >Ayuda asistencial:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="botonera">      
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                        <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                            <div class="group">
                                <!--<input type="text" name="PDI" value="0" size="4" id="PDI" disabled>-->

                                <input name="PDI" value="0" size="4" id="PDI" disabled="" type="text">



                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <label for="PDI">Porcentaje de Incapacidad</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>          
                <div class="botonera">
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha exiit">
                        <!--<a href="../views/paso-02.jsp" class="exit" >Regresar</a>-->
                        <a href="paso-02.jsp" onclick="regresarPaso2(event);return false;" class="exit">Regresar</a>
                        <!--<a href="../views/paso-02.jsp" class="exit">Regresar</a>-->
                    </div>
                    <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                        <button type="submit" id="loginButton"   onclick="enviar(event);">Siguiente</button>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </form>



        </div>

        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
//            setVersionDL();
//            setPageInstanceID("des");
//            setPageIntent("informacion");
//            setPageSegment("personas");
//            setSysEnv("escritorio");
//            setChannel("online");
//            setLanguage("ES");
//            setGeoRegion("MX");
//            setLevel(1, "pensiones");
//            setLevel(2, "simulador pensiones");
//            setLevel(3, "3 datos de la pension");
//            setArea("publica");
//            setPageName();//setPageName("publica:personas:home:tarjetas de credito:simulador tarjeta de credito:1 simulador");
//            setServer();
//            setBussinessUnit("BBVA Bancomer");
//            setMobile();
//            setUserState("no logado");
//            setType("simulador");
//            setName("simulador pensiones");
//            setFulfillmentModel("online");
//            //setProcess( "simulador pensiones" );
//            setStep("3 datos de la pension");
//            //setState();
//            setPrimaryCategory("inversiones");
//            setProductName(string_pension.toLowerCase());
//            setProductSubtype("planes de pensiones");
//            setUserAgent();
//            setTypology("");
//            //setProgramTypeHired(string_seguro.toLowerCase());
//            //_satellite.track("huellaAvanzadaPartePublica");


//            $('input').blur(function () {
//                var $this = $(this);
//                if ($this.val())
//                    $this.addClass('used');
//                else
//                    $this.removeClass('used');
//            });

            $(window, document, undefined).ready(function () {

                $('input').blur(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.val())
                        $this.addClass('used');
                    else
                        $this.removeClass('used');
                });




            });


        </script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>-->
    </body>





    <script>
        $(function () {
            //Limpiar Campos
            $('#corregir').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            $('#SP').val('');
                limpiar();
            });
            //Enviar
            $('#enviar').click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                metodoPost();
                if (ercapt == 1) {
                    var todosLlenos = false;

                    if ($('#SP').val() == '') {
                        todosLlenos = false;
                        $(".SP_alert").text("Introduce un monto en pesos");
                        $("#SP").css("border-bottom", "solid 1px #D44B50");
                        $("#SP").css("background-color", "#FCDFDF");
                        $('#SP').focus();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        todosLlenos = true;
                        $(".SP_alert").hide();
                        $("#SP").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #121212");
                        $("#SP").css("background-color", "#F4F4F4");
                    }



                    if (todosLlenos) {
                        $('#formreporta').submit();
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            //Validar Campos
            function isNumero() {
                var sp = $('#SP').val();
                if (/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ\s]*$/.test(sp)) {

                    $('#SP').val('');
                    $(".SP_alert").text("Introduce un monto en pesos");
                    $(".SP_alert").show();
                    $('#SP').css("border-bottom", "solid 1px #D44B50");
                    $('#SP').css("background-color", " #FCDFDF");
                    $('#SP').focus();
                    return false;
                } else if (/!^([0-9]{2,8}(.){0,1}[0-9]{2})*$/.test(sp)) {

                    $('#SP').val('');
                    $(".SP_alert").text("Introduce un monto en pesos");
                    $(".SP_alert").show();
                    $('#SP').css("border-bottom", "solid 1px #D44B50");
                    $('#SP').css("background-color", " #FCDFDF");
                    $('#SP').focus();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $(".SP_alert").hide();
                    $("#SP").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #121212");
                    $("#SP").css("background-color", "#F4F4F4");
                    return true;
                }
            }

            $('#SP').change(function () {
                isNumero();
            });



        });
    </script>




















</html>
```

Espero y me puedan orientar con este problema. De antemano les mando un cordial saludo.

Comment: Hola amigos, voy a probar con el href vacío como lo dice este blidge,  les aviso cómo me fue, ahorita ando fuera de mi lugar pero en un rato más revisare y les aviso con gusto cómo quedó :)

Answer (score 1):

Elimina  la etiqueta -->a href="paso-02.jsp">
y el evento onclick colócalo directamente en el botón.

Comment: El detalle que la etiqueta <a> ya esta por defecto en los demas formularios, hay alguna manera de que se haga con esa etiqueta??

Comment: Esto es un comentarío, @Blidge deberías explicar que beneficios tendría Juan al realizar este cambio.

Comment: Entiendo  Jorgesys, lo que pasa es que al darle clic te dirige a la vista que le especificas en href, y ahi solo le estas poniendo paso-02.jsp sin parametros, asi que solo dejalo en blanco href=""

Comment: Hola de nuevo, asi fue como quedo!  <a href="" class="exit" onclick="Regresar(event);">Regresar</a>

Answer (score 0):

asi como quedo,

```
<a href="" class="exit" onclick="Regresar(event);">Regresar</a>
```

Y el detalle que sigue sin funcionar, o igual soy libre de que me pudiesen pasar un ejemplo con Jquery para que me borre los parametros que no estan siendo enviados y me vuelva a cargar la pagina anterior, por favor, saludos